# Optimizing the layout of a graph with given (erroneous) node-distances

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, mathematical-optimization

I have a loosely connected graph. For every edge in this graph, I know the approximate distance *d(v,w)* between node *v* and *w* at positions *p(v)* and *p(w)* as **a vector in R3**, not only as an euclidean distance. The error shall be small (lets say < 3%) and the first node is at <0,0,0>.

If there were no errors at all, I can calculate the node-positions this way:

```
set p(first_node) = <0,0,0>
calculate_position(first_node)

calculate_position(v):
    for (v,w) in Edges:
        if p(w) is not set:
            set p(w) = p(v) + d(v,w)
            calculate_position(w)
    for (u,v) in Edges:
        if p(u) is not set:
            set p(u) = p(v) - d(u,v)
            calculate_position(u)
```

The errors of the distance are not equal. But to keep things simple, assume the relative error *(d(v,w)-d'(v,w))/E(v,w)* is N(0,1)-normal-distributed. I want to minimize the sum of the squared error

```
sum( ((p(v)-p(w)) - d(v,w) )^2/E(v,w)^2 ) for all edges
```

The graph may have a moderate amount of Nodes ( > 100 ) but with just some connections between the nodes and have been "prefiltered" (split into subgraphs, if there is only one connection between these subgraphs).

I have tried a simplistic "physical model" with [hooks low](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_%28device%29#Hooke.27s_law) but its slow and unstable. Is there a better algorithm or heuristic for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). Take error terms of the following form, i.e. without squares and split into separate coordinates:

```
(px(v) - px(w) - dx(v,w))/E(v,w)
(py(v) - py(w) - dy(v,w))/E(v,w)
(pz(v) - pz(w) - dz(v,w))/E(v,w)
```

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for values `px(v)`, `py(v)` and `pz(v)` for all nodes `v` such that the sum of squares of the above terms is minimized.

You can do this by creating a matrix *A* and a vector *b* in the following way: every *row* corresponds to one of *equation* of the above form, and every *column* of *A* corresponds to one *variable*, i.e. a single coordinate. For *n* vertices and *m* edges, the matrix *A* will have 3*m* rows (since you separate coordinates) and 3*n*−3 columns (since you also fix the first node `px(0)=py(0)=pz(0)=0`).

The row for `(px(v) - px(w) - dx(v,w))/E(v,w)` would have an entry `1/E(v,w)` in the column for `px(v)` and an entry `-1/E(v,w)` in the column for `px(w)`. All other columns would be zero. The corresponding entry in the vector *b* would be `dx(v,w)/E(v,w)`.

Now solve the [linear equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) (*A*<sup>T</sup>·*A*)*x* = *A*<sup>T</sup>·*b* where *A*<sup>T</sup> denotes the [transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of *A*. The solution vector *x* will contain the coordinates for your vertices. You can break this into three independent problems, one for each coordinate direction, to keep the size of the linear equation system down.

Comment: I had a similar idea on the next day. Least squares -- yet again;) Good point for solving each dimension on its own. Thank you.